# Database vs flat files in python (need speed but can't fit in memory) to be used with generator for NN training

Tags: python, database, pandas, data-structures, bigdata

I am dealing with a relatively large dataset (>400 GB) for analytics purposes but have somewhat limited memory (256 GB). I am using python. So far I have been using pandas on a subset of the data but it is becoming obvious that I need a solution that allows me to access data from the entire dataset.

A little bit about the data. Right now the data is segregated over a set of flat files that are pandas dataframes. The files consist of column that have 2 keys. The primary key, let's call it "record", which I want to be able to use to access the data, and a secondary key, which is basically row number within the primary key. As in I want to access row 2 in record "A".

The dataset is used for training a NN (keras/tf). So the task is to partition the entire set into train/dev/test by record, and then pass the data to train/predict generators (I implement keras.utils.Sequence(), which I have to do because the data is variable length sequences that need to be padded for batch learning).

Given my desire to pass examples to the NN as fast as possible and my inability to store all of the examples in memory, should I use a database (mongodb or sqlite or something else?) and query examples as needed, or should I continue to store things in flat files and load them/delete them (and hope that python garbage collector works)?

Another complication is that there are about 3mil "records". Right now the pandas dataframes store them in batches of ~10k, but it would benefit me to split the training/test/validation randomly, which means I really need to be able to access some but not all of the records in a particular batch. In pandas this seems hard (as in as far as I know I need to read the entire flat file to then access the particular record since I don't know in which chunk of the file the data is located), on the other hand I don't think generating 3mil individual files is smart either.

A further complication is that the model is relatively simple and I am unable due to various bottlenecks to saturate my compute power during training, so if I could stream the training to several different models that would help with hyperparameter search, since otherwise I am wasting cycles.

What do you think is the correct (fast, simple) back-end to handle my data needs?

Best,

Ilya

Comment: 3 million records in 400 Gbytes means that each record is about 130,000 bytes long.  I seriously doubt your are going to get any sort of useful model with a neural network.

Comment: Each record contains multiple rows (between 150 to 500). We are predicting on each row but since rows within one record are correlated we don't want to mix rows from the same record between train/test. The model already works very well ( better than our rule based system/other alternatives), but we hope to improve it/scale it up by feeding more data if we can.

Comment: On another note, 130kb is a 200x200 px 3 channel int8 image. Which is not an atypical size in image processing. But yeah, we're dealing with a small model that processes a short character sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case for writing a custom generator, then using Keras' model.fit_generator. Here's something I wrote the other day in conjunction with Pandas.

Note that I first split my main dataframe into training and validation splits (merged was my original dataframe), but you may have to move things around on disk and specify them when selecting in the generator

Lots of the reshaping and lookup/loading is all custom to my problem, but you see the pattern.

```
msk = np.random.rand(len(merged)) < 0.8
train = merged[msk]
valid = merged[~msk]

def train_generator(batch_size):
    sample_rows = train[train['match_id'].isin(npf.id.values)].sample(n=batch_size)
    sample_file_ids = sample_rows.FILE_NAME.tolist()
    sample_data = [np.load('/Users/jeff/spectro/' + x.split(".")[0] + ".npy").T for x in sample_file_ids]
    sample_data = [x.reshape(x.shape[0], x.shape[1]) for x in sample_data]
    sample_data = np.asarray([x[np.random.choice(x.shape[0], 128, replace=False)] for x in sample_data])
    sample_labels = np.asarray([labels.get(x) for x in sample_file_ids])

    while True:
        yield (sample_data, sample_labels)
```

It essentially returns batch_size samples whenever you call it. Keras requires your generator to return a tuple of length 2, where the first element is your data in the expected shape (whatever your neural network input shape is) and the labels to also map to the expected shape (N_classes, or whatever).

Here's another relatively useful link regarding generator, which may help you determine when you've truly exhausted all examples. My generator just randomly samples, but the dataset is sufficiently large that I don't care.

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7729#issuecomment-324627132

Don't forget to write a validation_generator as well, which is reading from some set of files or dataframes which you randomly put in some other place, for validation purposes.

Lastly, here's calling the generator:

```
model.fit_generator(train_generator(32), 
                    samples_per_epoch=10000, nb_epoch=20, 
                    validation_data=valid_generator(32), validation_steps=500)
```

depending on the keras version, you may find arg names have changed slightly, but a few searches should get you fixed up quickly.

Comment: Ok, thanks. As mentioned I am already using a generator (built on top of keras.utils.Sequence()). 

I actually really like the idea of presorting data into train/valid/test flat files and then reading those files a chunk at a time. I think I will give this a try! Thanks.

Comment: Cool yeah I don't think you need any special backend then.